# Design Camera Frame using python tkinter

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, camera

I want to build an app using python that has a button , the button opens camera after click,
but I want to design the camera frame while its opening .the design is something like this image, but the white space in the middle is what camera shows.
[image]

I tried using an image which is transparent in the middle but it didn't worked.

for create the design I tried using Canvas too but it just runs one time and the second time the circle doesn't show up.

this is the last code I am working on, it doesn't have the shape I want and have the camera problem I mentioned.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2
from tkinter import PhotoImage

main_root = Tk()
main_root.withdraw()

splash_root = Toplevel()
splash_root.geometry("800x480")
splash_root.overrideredirect(True)
bg = PhotoImage(file="image/tc.png")
lab = Label(splash_root, image=bg)
lab.pack()


def main():
    splash_root.withdraw()
    # splash_root.destroy()

    root = Toplevel()
    root.geometry("800x480")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.title("")

    WIDTH = 800
    HEIGHT = 480
    
    cam_on = False
    cap = None
    # cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def first_window():
        frame = Frame(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="#edf5ef")
        frame.place(x=0, y=0)

        border1 = LabelFrame(root, bd=2, bg="black", fg="black", width=160, height=61)
        border1.place(x=80, y=300)
        
        newExamBtn = Button(
            root,
            text="New Exam",
            bg="#c1d4c6",
            font=("Helvatical", 13),
            padx=36,
            pady=15,
            border=0,
            command=newExam,
        )
        newExamBtn.place(x=82, y=302)

    def newExam():
        frameNE = Frame(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="white")
        frameNE.place(x=0, y=0)

        backBtn = Button(
            root,
            bg="white",
            activebackground="white",
            border=0,
            width=64,
            height=64,
            image=backImgGray,
            command=first_window,
        )
        backBtn.place(x=0, y=0)

        examBtnBorder = LabelFrame(
            frameNE, bd=2, bg="gray", fg="white", width=200, height=80
        )
        examBtnBorder.place(x=300, y=100)

        examBtnIcn = Label(root, bg="gray", image=examImg)
        examBtnIcn.place(x=310, y=105)

        examBtn = Button(
            frameNE,
            text="Exam",
            bg="gray",
            fg="white",
            activebackground="gray",
            activeforeground="white",
            border=0,
            font=("Helvatical", 20),
            command=Camera,
        )
        examBtn.place(x=380, y=110)


    def start_vid():
        global cam_on, cap
        # stop_vid()
        cam_on = True
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
        show_frames()

    def stop_vid():
        global cam_on, cap
        cam_on = False
        
        if cap:
            cap.release()
        cap = None
        

    def show_frames():
        global cap , cam_on

        labelCam =Label(root)
        labelCam.pack()
        if cam_on:

            # ret, frame = cap.read()
                        
            # Get the latest frame and convert into Image
            cv2image= cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1],cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            # Convert image to PhotoImage
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img)
            labelCam.imgtk = imgtk
            labelCam.configure(image=imgtk)
            # Repeat after an interval to capture continiously
            labelCam.after(10, show_frames)    

            # if ret:
            #     cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)    
            #     img = Image.fromarray(cv2image).resize((810,640))
            #     imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)        
            #     labelCam.imgtk = imgtk    
            #     labelCam.configure(image=imgtk)    
            
            # labelCam.after(10, show_frames)

    def closeCam_and_Back():
        stop_vid()
        newExam()

    def Camera():
        frameC = Frame(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="#edf5ef")
        frameC.place(x=0, y=0)
        # IMAGE_PATH = 'image/Untitled11.png'
        # canvas = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
        # canvas.pack()

        start_vid()

        # img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(IMAGE_PATH).resize((WIDTH, HEIGHT), Image.ANTIALIAS))
        # canvas.background = img  # Keep a reference in case this code is put in a function.
        # bg = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=img)
        
        backBtn = Button(
            frameC,
            bg="#353b36",
            activebackground="#353b36",
            border=0,
            width=50,
            height=32,
            image=backImg32,
            command=closeCam_and_Back,
        )
        backBtn.place(x=0, y=0)

        

        



    first_window()


backImg32 = Image.open("image/icons8-left-64.png").resize((32, 32), Image.LANCZOS)
backImg32 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(backImg32)

backImgGray = Image.open("image/icons8-left-64-gray.png").resize((50, 50), Image.LANCZOS)
backImgGray = ImageTk.PhotoImage(backImgGray)

examImg = PhotoImage(file="image/icons8-exam-64.png")


splash_root.after(3000, main)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Try using SO search. Enter '[tkinter] cv camera' this will return a list of possible solutions.

Comment: Use `Canvas` widget to show the images because `Canvas` widget supports transparency in image.  Then you can overlay the *control panel image with transparency in the middle* over the camera image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Canvas` widget to show images with transparency.  Just put the image for camera feed with the image with transparency in the middle overlay on-top.

Below is the image with transparency in the middle:

[image]

Below is an example of showing a video behind the above image:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

# define the video size
w, h = 640, 360

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

# image for showing the camera feed
tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage("RGB", (w, h))
video = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tkimg, anchor="nw")

# image overlay on top of the above image
panel = tk.PhotoImage(file="panel.png")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=panel, anchor="nw")

#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# use a video file instead for demostration
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("TheDivision2.mp4")

def play_video():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = Image.fromarray(frame)
        tkimg.paste(image)
    root.after(20, play_video)

play_video() # start playing the video

root.mainloop()
```

The output:

[image]